# Cross Platform ~2GB File Upload Solution

Tags: java, upload, air

I'm looking for a technology that can be used to upload large (~2GB) files from both Windows and Mac OSX machines. It should be possible to pause and resume uploads on request/error. The final artefact should be easily installed by a user with basic computer skills.

I'm thinking of using Adobe AIR as it's quite ubiquitous, so installing should be easy although I'm not sure that AIR would provide the power that we're after. Another option would be a Java app, which I believe would provide more choice in terms which upload protocols (HTTP/WebDAV/etc).

Does AIR have the power to handle such large file sizes and could it pause and resume? Would Java be better, as I could chunk the files more easily? Is there another solution that I've not thought of? Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Please don't suggest using a service like YouSendIt, DropBox, etc. I need a custom, branded solution that can be integrated with a CMS for the uploaded files.

Thanks!

Darren.

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this yet?

Comment: Are you adding this into your cms as a webpage, or is this a standalone program that will interface with the cms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Apache [FileUpload library](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) which I've tested uploading about 4gigs to, and it didn't have any problems.

If you want more control I would advise an applet - more control and you still have the advantage of not having to install on the clients computer.

Comment: Yeah have seen that recently, will probably still use the applet in the end.